# Get url from file uploaded in Media Library

Tags: urls, page-template, attachments, media, media-library

I have a file called Portfolio.zip in my Media Library which will always have this name.

Now in my page template I need the url to this file. I can achieve this via his id : wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); but I would like to get the URL by the name "Portfolio.zip" as I know for sure this will always be the same.

**My Code:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <a id="download" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-color-grey"
                    href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( 2582 ); ?>" title="Download Portfolio">Download My Portfolio</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any Ideas?

Grts,
Nanou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find attachment by it's name?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/117087/70833)

Answer (score 2):

If understand your question correctly, I think this can get the job done. Use `get_attachment_link` instead of `wp_get_attachment_url` and then echo the title.

```
<?php 
 $attachment_id = 2582;
 $attachment_page = get_attachment_link( $attachment_id ); 
?>
<a href="<?php echo $attachment_page; ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($attachment_id ); ?></a>
```

Comment: Hi thx for answering but I think you misunderstood. I don't need the title. I want the URL but by name and not by id.