# Finding a media attachment post ID from a URL

Tags: media

Given I have an image URL

And that the image has previously been saved in the media library

How can I find the media's ID?

i.e.

https://somesite.com/uploads/pic1.jpg                     might be ID 4

https://somesite.com/uploads/pic1.jpg-scaled-300x300.jpeg is also ID 4

Given I have the URL, how do I find the ID?

```
function returnMediaID($URL){
   ... // What goes here?
}

$URL = "https://somesite.com/uploads/pic1.jpg";
assertEquals( returnMediaID($URL), 4);
```

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117069/how-to-find-attachment-by-its-name/117087